# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Unable to access Worklight Server through Android device

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am trying to run an application on my Android device. The server is accessible through my browser and Android Emulator.

But the device (also connected to the same network as my Worklight Server) is unable to access the Worklight server. Giving me the following error in logcat:

> 09-13 00:30:38.168: E/locationServices(4826):
>
> ```
> [http://172.20.14.181:10080/location/apps/services/api/locationServices/android/query] Host is not responsive. Try 
>
> to manually access the URL through the android emulator browser to verify connectivity.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the Worklight builder is picking the wrong IP address in case you have several in your machine.

Try choosing `Build for Remote Server` instead. Use your external IP address in the dialog options.
This will generate the Android project based on the connection details you've entered.

Next, run the generated Android project on the device and see if it connects to the Worklight Server this time around.

Note: do **not** run `Build All and Deploy` or `Build Specific Environment` as it will override the changes you've made when running using `Build for Remote Server`.

Comment: I tried giving external IP with the 10080, but I am getting "Request time out for my ExternalIp:10080"

Comment: If you open the mobile browser app in your Android device and try to load 172.20.14.181:10080/location/console or yourPublicIP:10080/location/console, does it work?

Comment: Then on first thought - your device cannot reach the server despite you thinking they are in the same network; how many IP addresses do you have there?

Comment: My system has its own local IP and device has its own ip address:
Local IP address is: 172.20.14.181
Device IP address is: 172.20.15.156

Comment: Again, both need to be in the same network, otherwise the device won't be able to connect to the server, as evident from it not being able to load worklight console, if it doesn't reach the console, it doesn't reach the server.

Comment: I get what you are saying. Let me try with a different connection. Thanks.

Comment: Finally, my external ip should be global right? Why isn't it working for that?

Comment: Should we port forward from the router for external ip?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the application first before running it from Eclipse into your Android device.

In my case my older application was still running and looking for an old IP address. Uninstalling it solved the problem and made sure the new application is running and looking for the updated IP address I had.